# How do I return a list with the five oldest dates?

Tags: excel

So I have a list - see example:

[image]

I want a function to check the complete list (imagine there is more than 1 entry), and returns with f.i. the 5 oldest rows (sorted by data in row B). As in complete rows.

I can get the lowest through:

```
=MIN(C3:C29)
```

But that doesn't seem as something usable for this no matter how I do it.

Then I though I could use the INDEX/LARGE functions (or MATCH? Would that be possible?), but I'm too stupid to make it work atm.
Is this even the right way?

I can make a macro doing it (filtering, copying first lines etc - stupid) but I know there is a smarter way of doing it.

Can anyone help me on my way or tell me if I'm looking up the wrong functions for this? Please tell me if I need more details.

Thanks

Comment: Use `SORT()` and `INDEX()` for example.

Comment: small() may be another option.

Answer (score 0):

So, try this:

[image]

Cells formatted as shortdate.

And it works with months as well:

[image]